# Jmeter transaction per minute

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

How to achieve transactions per minute in jmeter while using transaction controller instead of request level?

For example, in the below screenshot i want to achieve transaction_2 and transaction_3 to achieve 100/minute.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot apply a Constant Throughput Timer to an individual sampler because due to JMeter waits for previous sampler to complete prior to starting the next one so you will always be getting the throughput of the slowest Sampler
2. Constant Throughput Timer treats samplers **individually** therefore you need to multiply the throughput for the transaction by the number of its children samplers, i.e. if the [transaction controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) has 3 child samplers and you want the whole transaction to be executed 100 times/minute - you need to set the target throughput to 300 requests/minute

   [image]

as you can see the throughput of 50 requests minute per sampler has transformed into 10 requests/minute for the whole transaction
3. Constant Throughput Timer can only **pause** the requests to slow JMeter's throughput to the desired value, if you need to "achieve" some throughput by speeding JMeter up it's better to consider [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) combination